# How to increase or decrease the values ​of multiple inputs of array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, input, increment, decrement

So that's it:

`const [count, setCount] = useState(1 as any)`

`{items.map((item: any) => (...`

Then items of array are mapped in shopping cart. I want to be able to increase or decrease the quantity.

```
<input
 type="number"
 min="1"
 value={count}
 onChange={(event): any => {
 setCount(event.target.value)
 }}
/>
```

It changes the value of all items. But I want to change the value of the elements independently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(items); // items array []

const onTextChanged = (index, value) => {
    const items = [...items]; 
    items[index].count = value; <-- "count" is example key for showing way out of this -->
    setItems(items);
}

{items.map((item, index) => (

 <input
  type="number"
  min="1"
  value={item.count || 0}
  onChange={(event): any => {
    onTextChanged(index, event.target.value)
  }}
 />

)}
```

Comment: It seems good, but I have no data value. `setItems(data)`

Comment: setItems is a way to reset state with new data set using Hooks. This way all counts maintained separately

Comment: 'data' is not defined

Comment: Now the input fields shows the value but doesn't respond to the up and down arrows.